# TextInputLayout label interferring with entered text

Tags: android, layout, material-design

In my new Android app, the label of the TextInputLayout appears in the space where the user types the input. This causes the entered text to render on top of the label/hint:

When the user first loads the page:
[image: When the user first loads the page]

When the user taps on the text input, the label shrinks towards the top left as expected:
[image: When the user taps on the text input]

When the user types an entry, it types over the label:
[image: When the user types an entry]

I have two questions:

1. What is the appropriate behavior here following Material Design guidelines?
2. How do I accomplish this behavior?

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch"
    tools:context=".ui.JobsDetailsFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_new_position"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/new_position"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_new_position">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/text_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/title"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/text_business_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/business_name" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/position_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:contentDescription="@string/position_save"
        android:src="@drawable/done"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Update

I tried moving `android:hint` to the `TextInputLayout` and still see the same behavior:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/title"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_new_position">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/text_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

For reference, here is `themes.xml`:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.JobSearch" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.JobSearch.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.JobSearch.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.JobSearch.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

Comment: `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` constraint .. Not sure if that not in place as `TextInputEditText` not surrounded by `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: @Zain WIll you please post your suggestion as an answer with a more complete XML code. If you are referring to the second code snippet, I show only a modified version of the `TextInputLayout` from the first code snippet.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to use multiple **app:layout_constraints**? Try removing all `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"`  and in TextInputEditText, remove the line `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`.

Comment: @Darkman Please post an answer including any clarifying details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replicated your issue and the problem is because your using  **android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch"** in your TextInputLayout or TextInputEditText. Remove all **android:theme** attributes from all TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText and use your own style instead which will be applied only to your TextInputLayout like **style="@style/MyTextInputLayoutStyle"**.

I have modified your xml layout using a custom style for each TextInputLayout like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch"
    tools:context=".ui.JobsDetailsFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_new_position"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/new_position"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/title"
        style="@style/MyTextInputLayoutStyle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_new_position">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/text_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/business_name"
        style="@style/MyTextInputLayoutStyle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/text_business_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/position_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:contentDescription="@string/position_save"
        android:src="@drawable/done"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

where style="@style/MyTextInputLayoutStyle" is your custom style for the TextInputLayout like below:

```
<style name="MyTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_box_stroke_color</item>
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

and i have set a color selector for your boxStrokeColor (@color/text_input_box_stroke_color) to change the underline bottom stroke color based on the focused/default state like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/teal_200" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/teal_200" android:state_hovered="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</selector>
```

And the final result after the above changes will be like this:

[image: textInputLayout]

Comment: I tested out your suggestion to remove the theme declarations from the TextInputLayout. I also removed it from the ConstraintLayout. That solves the problem with the positioning. I think I added the explicit theme initially to change the background from gray to white. After looking at the Material UI docs, it looks like a gray background is the default. I'll look further into the default styles and figure out from there what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#filled-text-field

> Note: The android:hint should always be set on the TextInputLayout instead of on the EditText in order to avoid unintended behaviors.

I think this is your problem.

Update: Try this code for the first box:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/title_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/title"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_new_position">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/text_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

This removes the line `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` and changes the height field to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: Thanks for your suggstion. While that might help avoid other issues, it doesn't solve the problem I asked about here.

Comment: Your second suggestion still doesn't work. Maybe this has something to do with my theme? I seem to have to apply `android:theme` to every `TextInputLayout` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/text_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="@string/title"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I am afraid that `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` constraint could be removed as `TextInputEditText` is not a direct child of a `ConstraintLayout` or probably transferred to the surrounding `TextInputLayout` which is a direct child of the `ConstraintLayout`

Applying the latter to the layout, taking the sugguestion of @Jems into consideration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch"
    tools:context=".ui.JobsDetailsFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_new_position"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/new_position"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
        android:hint="@string/title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_new_position">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/text_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch"
        android:hint="@string/business_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/text_business_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/position_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:contentDescription="@string/position_save"
        android:src="@drawable/done"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this out as a complete answer. I copy-pasted the complete layout from your answer into my app and I still see the same behavior as in my original question. Any suggestions about what else to try?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks so much for your comment .. Can you add `app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"` to the `textInputLayout` .. this is the default behavior but I am afraid it could be accidentally disabled programmatically or something ..  also could you share `@style/Theme.JobSearch` or you can remove it for a while and try to test without it .. I couldn't reproduce the issue.. your feedback is appreciated

Comment: The hint animates fine as far as I can tell, but the final position after the animation is such that the hint and entered text overlap.

Comment: And I added `themes.xml` to my question above. It's is pretty standard and bare-bones, only declaring the primary and secondary colors of the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to say, it's quite obvious. You have to test it for yourself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch"
    tools:context=".ui.JobsDetailsFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_new_position"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/new_position"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_new_position">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/text_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/title"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.JobSearch"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/text_business_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/business_name" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

 
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/position_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:contentDescription="@string/position_save"
        android:src="@drawable/done"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will you explain in words what changes I need to make?